# Jest, mongoose and async/await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jestjs

i have a mongoose model in the node. I want to get all record from that in my test suite with the jest. here is my test:

```
test('should find and return all active coupon codes ', async () => {
    const res = await CouponModel.find({ active: true });
    expect(res).toBeDefined();
    const s = res;
    console.log(s);
  });
```

as you can see i used async/await. I get following timeout error:

```
  ● coupon code test › should find and return all active coupon codes 

Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

  at node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:64:21
  at ontimeout (timers.js:478:11)
  at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:302:5)
  at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:262:5)
```

where I did a mistake? how can I fix this?

Comment: This seems like a weird thing to test, why would you test if mongoose.find is working in your code? Also queries in mongoose like .find does not return actual promises (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add assertions for your async results.

> `expect.assertions(number)` verifies that a certain number of
>   assertions are called during a test. This is often useful when testing
>   asynchronous code, in order to make sure that assertions in a callback
>   actually got called.

```
test('should find and return all active coupon codes ', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const res = await CouponModel.find({ active: true });
    expect(res).toBeDefined();
    const s = res;
    console.log(s);
  });
```

With error:

```
test('should find and return all active coupon codes ', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    try {
        const res = await CouponModel.find({ active: true });
        expect(res).toBeDefined();
    } catch (e) {
        expect(e).toEqual({
        error: 'CouponModel with 1 not found.',
    });
  });
```

Comment: expected one assertion but received zero assertion calls.I think something wrong with mongo and jest. because exactly this code working fine in API section. but not in the test

Comment: @amir any update on this error, I am also facing the same issue. I went through these issues on jest repo https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3045 but could not draw much help from it.